# Polyline node order

Tags: python, pyqgis, line, nodes

I was looking for a tool/mechanism for determining node order in a polyline shapefile.  For this exercise, node order would be the number of polylines attached to each node.  A dangling node would be order 1, a pseudo node would be order 2, a node with 3 polylines attached would be order 3 and so on.  What I came up with was the following script and was wondering if there are tools already built in to QGIS that might do the same thing.  The script below distinguishes between what one might consider a "true dangling node" (order 1) from a dangling node that "touches" another polyline (either at a vertex or along an edge) by adding a period and the number of lines intersected by the bounding box of the node to the node order column.  (eg. 1 vs 1.2).

I am aware of issues using floating point numbers for things like this, but in my case formatting numbers to 7 decimal places is OK - it might not be OK in other circumstances.  I did test this on a shapefile with about 16,600 features and it took 30 seconds to run.  If a dataset had hundreds of thousands of features, it might not be so efficient.

I'd be interested in hearing thoughts on this subject.  No doubt there are better/more efficient ways of accomplishing the same thing.

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
project = QgsProject.instance()

feat = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
bfeat = QgsFeature(layer.fields())

nodeLayer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:2961","node_layer","memory")
buffLayer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:2961","buff_layer","memory")

pr = nodeLayer.dataProvider()
prBuff = buffLayer.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField('NodeOrder',QVariant.String)])
nodeLayer.updateFields()

pntDict = {}

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    geom= feat.geometry().asMultiPolyline()
    strKey = "{0:.7f}, {1:.7f}".format(geom[0][0].x(), geom[0][0].y())

    if not strKey in pntDict:
        pntDict[strKey] = 1
    else:
        pntDict[strKey] = pntDict[strKey] + 1

    strKey = "{0:.7f}, {1:.7f}".format(geom[-1][-1].x(), geom[-1][-1].y())

    if not strKey in pntDict:
        pntDict[strKey] = 1
    else:
        pntDict[strKey] = pntDict[strKey] + 1

for key, value in pntDict.items():
    xy = key.split(",")
    newPnt = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(float(xy[0]),float(xy[1])))
    buff = newPnt.buffer(0.0000001,1)
    brect = buff.boundingBox()
    layer.selectByRect(brect,0)
if layer.selectedFeatureCount() != value:
    value = str(value) + '.' + str(layer.selectedFeatureCount())

feat.setAttributes([value])
feat.setGeometry(newPnt)
pr.addFeatures([feat])

project.instance().addMapLayer(nodeLayer)
```

Comment: It seems as if you are looking for a code review or discussion, but these aren't really GIS SE strenghts. In theory, the [chat] feature could be used for this sort of discussion, but in reality, Chat is *underutilized*. You should probably make sure you have a spatial index built (or switch to a format with standard spatial indexes).

Comment: If you're comfortable using PostGIS it looks like there is a function GetNodeEdges that may be close to what you are looking for. See http://www.postgis.us/downloads/postgis21_topology_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Thanks Vince.  I was wondering if this was the best place to post the question.  I do have a spatial index on the shapefile so no issues on that front.  I'm just starting to get into QGIS (have used ArcGIS/ESRI for a couple of decades) and was wondering if there might have been some functionality that isn't obvious to me.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I am aware of PostGIS, but have never used it.  I may download it and take a peek at it.